# How to use virtual cam in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, obs

I heard myself finding Obs' virtual cam in Android Studio in an Android emulator for 6 hours, but only my plugged in cam is recognized. How else can I do that, I have this possibility in my head for which I have not found a solution online.

I have to try the virtual cam as an applied cam or a real cam.

or if someone has another idea please say and no, I have to use the virtual cam from Obs so that I have a screen and cam on the virtual cam.

I ask for help!

Thank you for the coming comments.